# Cartesian product counterexample

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give a simple example where the following result fails, and briefly explain why:

False theorem: For sets A, B, C, D let: 
$$L:== (A\cup B) \times (C\cup D) $$
$$ R:== (A\times C) \cup (B\times D) $$
Then $L = R$

Comment: If you think about it, $(A\cup B)\times (C\cup D)$ has four regions (if you think of $A,B,C,D$ as line segments) but $(A\times C)\cup (B\times D)$ has two regions.

Comment: Take A = C = {1}, B = D = {2}. $L = \{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)\}$, but $R = \{(1,1), (2,2)\}$.

Comment: Yeah, I worked out the cartesian products for A, B, C, D as sets of size 2 and I see immediately that the claim was false. However, I needed to find a way to generalize my findings into a concise proof if possible, I know the question asks for a counterexample, but just curious. Newbie at proofs and number theory!

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=\{1\}=D$, $B=\{2\}=C$, so $A\cup B = \{1,2\}=C\cup D$. So the product is $\{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2)\}$.

While $A\times C = \{(1,2)\}$ and $B\times D = \{(2,1)\}$. So $(A\times C) \cup (B\times D\} =\{(1,2), (2,1)\}$