# Cartesian product for sets: investigate faulty reasoning of fake proofs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, fake-proofs

This is related to another question, please see for the background of the problem:

[Cartesian product counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1468118/cartesian-product-counterexample)

Part II) Find the mistake in the following bogus proof of the False theorem and fix it to show that $R \subseteq L$

Proof: Since L and R are both sets of pairs, it's sufficient to prove that 
$(x,y) \in L \iff (x,y) \in R$ for all $x,y$

The proof will be a chain of iff implications: 
$$(x,y) \in R$$
$$\iff (x,y) \in (A \times C) \cup (B \times D)$$
$$\iff (x,y) \in A \times C \text{, or } (x,y) \in B \times D $$
$$\iff (x \in A \text { and } y \in C) \text { or else } (x \in B \text { and } y \in D) $$
$$\iff \text{either } x \in A \text{ or } x \in B, \text { and either } y \in C \text{ or } y \in D$$
$$\iff x \in A \cup B \text { and } y \in C \cup D$$
$$\iff (x, y) \in L$$

Comment: look at line 4 and 5, in line 5 we have that x can be in A and y can be in D, but in line 4 it cannot be.

Comment: so how would it be fixed? How would the whole proof be fixed to show that $R \subseteq L$? I'm having trouble coming up with a simplification for 5 other than the original equation for $R$ itself

Comment: you have one-sided implication from line 4 to line 5, therefore, $R \subseteq L$.